# How can I parse an existing instance of a dependency to my BaseCommandModule in DSharp+ C# Discord Bot?

Tags: c#, dsharp+

I am writing a discord Bot in C# (With the help of DSharpPlus) that uses the VRChatAPI to open instances and invite a list of people to it (plus many more functions)

I have seen here: https://github.com/DSharpPlus/DSharpPlus/blob/master/docs/articles/commands/dependency_injection.md
that you can parse a dependency class to a `BaseCommandModule`.
Tho I would like to parse an already existing instace of said dependency to my `BaseCommandModule`because I want to have access to the same Information because i use it in many different areas.
Is this possible? if yes, How?

My code looks as follows:

My VRChat API Communicator class that i want to use and instance of:

```cs
public class VRCCommunicator
    {
        public string Status { get; private set; }

        Configuration Config;

        AuthenticationApi AuthApi;
        UsersApi UsersApi;
        WorldsApi WorldsApi;

        public CurrentUser currentUser { get; private set; }

        VRCCommunicator() 
        {
            var json = string.Empty;

            using (var sr = new StreamReader("configs\\vrchatconfig.json"))
                json = sr.ReadToEnd();

            var vRCConfigJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<VRChatConfigJson>(json);

            Config = new Configuration()
            {
                Username = vRCConfigJson.Username,
                Password = vRCConfigJson.Password
            };
            AuthApi = new AuthenticationApi(Config);
            UsersApi = new UsersApi(Config);
            WorldsApi = new WorldsApi(Config);
        }

        public async void logIn()
        {
            currentUser = await AuthApi.GetCurrentUserAsync();
            Status = "Logged in as: " + currentUser.DisplayName;
        }
    }
```

and the `BaseCommandModule` i want to use the instance in:

```cs
public class DebugCommands : BaseCommandModule
    {
        private VRCCommunicator VRCApi;

        [Command("login")]
        public async Task VRCLogIn(CommandContext ctx)
        {
            VRCApi.logIn();
            await ctx.Channel.SendMessageAsync(VRCApi.Status).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        [Command("vrchatstatus")]
        public async Task VRCStatus(CommandContext ctx)
        {
            await ctx.Channel.SendMessageAsync(VRCApi.Status).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
```

The way portrayed in the link above works but seems to create a new instance of `VRCCommunicator` every time the command is called

Edit: Forgot to add my base Bot class:

```cs
public class Bot
    {
        public DiscordClient Client { get; private set; }
        public CommandsNextExtension Commands { get; private set; }

        public VRCCommunicator VRCApi { get; private set; }


        public async Task RunAsync()
        {
            var json = string.Empty;

            using(var fs = File.OpenRead("configs\\botconfig.json"))
                using(var sr = new StreamReader(fs, new UTF8Encoding(false)))
                json = await sr.ReadToEndAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            
            var configJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BotConfigJson>(json);

            var config = new DiscordConfiguration()
            {
                Token = configJson.Token,
                TokenType = TokenType.Bot,
                Intents = DiscordIntents.All,
                AutoReconnect = true,
                MinimumLogLevel = LogLevel.Debug,
            };

            Client = new DiscordClient(config);
            Client.Ready += OnClientReady;

            var commandsConfig = new CommandsNextConfiguration
            {
                StringPrefixes = new string[] { configJson.Prefix },
                EnableMentionPrefix = true,
                EnableDms = true,
                CaseSensitive = true,
                DmHelp = true
            };

            Commands = Client.UseCommandsNext(commandsConfig);
            Commands.RegisterCommands<DebugCommands>();

            await Client.ConnectAsync();

            await Task.Delay(-1);
        }

        private Task OnClientReady(object sender, ReadyEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Bot Ready");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```